# I have a question about using provider in flutter

Tags: flutter

Hi Hello I am studying about provider in flutter.

I simply moved the sample code while studying, but the following error occurs.

Did library change or did I make an error?

[image]

```
class BankAccount with ChangeNotifier {
  int _balance = 0;

  int getBalance() => _balance;

  void increment(int value) {
    _balance += value;
    notifyListeners(); //must be inserted
  }

  void decrement(int value) {
    _balance -= value;
    notifyListeners(); //must be inserted
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider<BankAccount>(builder: (_) => BankAccount(),),//This is a problem
        Provider<String>.value(value: "Park")
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: "Provider Test",
        home: HomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    BankAccount bankAccount = Provider.of<BankAccount>(context);
    String name = Provider.of<String>(context);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Refer here](https://pub.dev/documentation/provider/latest/provider/ChangeNotifierProvider-class.html)

```
ChangeNotifierProvider(
  create: (_) => BankAccount(),
)
```